# Not able to fetch in-app subscriptions via Revenue-cat-react-native-sdk from google play store

Tags: android, react-native, in-app-subscription, revenuecat

I am using `Revenue-cat-react-native-sdk` for IOS and play store In-app subscriptions. It works flawlessly with IOS (after few days of hard time), but while using this same SDK with android it throws an error while fetching offerings.

Error Message:

```bash
[Error: There was a problem with the store.]
```

I have uploaded the build on google play store and created in app subscriptions for the same. I am also done with revenue cat configurations.

Also, does app needs to released for `closed testing` or any other testing in order to use subscriptions, because that's not the case for IOS ?

Comment: Yo need to release to closed testing once for Google to start sending the products to your app builds. You only need to upload the app once to the play store for testing, and subsequent builds installed from your computer should be able to load the products

Answer (score 2):

Yes. as per @Cesar 's comment you need to release your application to one of the following :

```
 1. internal testing
 2. closed testing
```

Comment: I did it. My app even was published to the Google Play but it shows the same error